# string aggregation and joining with another table column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions, business-intelligence

I have following tables:

```
weighment_tran
    village_cd
    farmer_id
    registered_farmer_id
    plot_no
    out_date
    net_wt

village_dir
    village_cd
    village_name
    taluka_cd
    district_cd

taluka_dir
    taluka_cd
    taluka_name

district_dir
    district_cd
    district_name

farmer_dir
    farmer_id
    first_name
    middle_name

agreement_tran
    farmer_id
    registered_farmer_id
    payment_farmer_id
    plot_no
    main_sy_no
    payment_bank_cd
    payment_account_no

bank_dir
    bank_cd
    bank_name
    bank_branch
```

Mainly I have two transaction tables namely `agreement_tran` (agreements are stored) and `weighment_tran` (weighment of products stored only those present in `agreement_tran`) and others are directories those holds lookup for actual names for codes like `bank_cd` looks for actual `bank_name` in `bank_dir`. `farmer_id`, `registered_farmer_id`, `payment_farmer_id` are of same column values. What I need is as below with `out_date` range:

```
Sl.No  farmer_name  Sy_nos  village  taluka  district  payment_farmer_id  payment_account_no  bank_name  bank_branch  sum(net_wt)
```

Every `plot_no` has a `sy_no`, I need to concatenate all `sy_no`s as I am selecting `sum(net_wt)` as `net_wt` concerned to every `plot_no`.

I tried something like-

```
select row_number() over (order by a.payment_farmer_id),
        a.payment_farmer_id, 
(select f.first_name ||' '|| f.middle_name as name
        from farmer_dir f 
        where a.payment_farmer_id=f.farmer_id),
(select wm_concat(main_sy_no) from agreement_tran a 
        where a.plot_no=w.plot_no),
(select sum(net_wt)
        from weighment_tran w
        where (w.plot_no = a.plot_no)
        and (w.season_cd = 9) and trunc(w.out_date) between 
        to_date('22-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('23-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') 
        group by a.payment_farmer_id)
from agreement_tran a
```

but didn't get what I want.

Comment: @Rachcha I entered what I tried so far. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Sum(WEIGHMENT_TRAN.NET_WT), 
AGREEMENT_TRAN.PAYMENT_FARMER_ID, 
wm_concat(Distinct (agreement_tran.main_sy_no)) as Sy_no,
wm_concat(Distinct (village_dir.village_name)) as Village,
farmer_dir.first_name || ' ' || farmer_dir.middle_name as Farmer_name,     taluka_dir.taluka_name, district_dir.district_name, bank_dir.bank_name, bank_dir.bank_branch,  agreement_tran.payment_account_no, weighment_tran.registered_farmer_id
FROM AGRI.AGREEMENT_TRAN AGREEMENT_TRAN,
AGRI.village_dir village_dir, 
AGRI.WEIGHMENT_TRAN WEIGHMENT_TRAN, 
agri.farmer_dir farmer_dir, agri.taluka_dir taluka_dir, 
agri.district_dir district_dir, agri.bank_dir bank_dir
WHERE AGREEMENT_TRAN.PLOT_NO = WEIGHMENT_TRAN.PLOT_NO AND
((AGREEMENT_TRAN.SEASON_CD=9) AND (WEIGHMENT_TRAN.SEASON_CD=9) AND 
(trunc(weighment_tran.out_date) Between to_date('22-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
And to_date('22-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')) AND
(AGREEMENT_TRAN.PLOT_NO=weighment_tran.plot_no) AND     (WEIGHMENT_TRAN.VILLAGE_CD=village_dir.village_cd)) and   agreement_tran.payment_farmer_id=farmer_dir.farmer_id and    village_dir.taluka_cd=taluka_dir.taluka_cd and    village_dir.district_cd=district_dir.district_cd and    agreement_tran.payment_bank_cd=bank_dir.bank_cd
GROUP BY AGREEMENT_TRAN.PAYMENT_FARMER_ID, farmer_dir.first_name, farmer_dir.middle_name, taluka_dir.taluka_name, district_dir.district_name,bank_dir.bank_name, bank_dir.bank_branch, agreement_tran.payment_account_no, weighment_tran.registered_farmer_id
Order by bank_dir.bank_name, bank_dir.bank_branch
```

finally I rewarded for my long effort and thanking @Thorsten for his time n patience.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some mistakes in your query:

1. First subquery looks okay.
2. Second subquery is wrong. You select agreement_tran a second time but use the same alias. Moreover you compare with w.plot_no, but there is no w table. (I suppose you meant to name the inner agreement_tran w?)
3. In your second subquery the group by clause makes no sense. Remove it.
4. Is it on purpose that you don't sort your results? Above you number your lines, but at the end of the query you have no order by, which may result in a random order.

Your query shows all agreements, their farmer's name, all sy nos of all agreements with the same plot number, and the sum of all net weights with the same plot number in a certain time slot. Please check if this is meets your expectations. Do you really want to select all Agreements or rather all plots for instance?

Comment: No.. I only need records those are present in 'weighment_tran'. I am bit confuse, how to do it!

Comment: You select "from agreement_tran a". This gives you all records from that table. If you records from weighment_tran instead, then either select from that table or join with it or limit your results with an IN or EXISTS clause to that table.

Comment: It is rather hard to help, because we don't know how your tables are related. You join with plot_no, but there is not even a table for plots it seems, which is not what would I have suspected. What are the keys of your tables, what makes a record unique? What is the meaning of the plot number?

Comment: farmer_id and Plot_no are the keys. plot_no is a unique number assigned to every plots. A farmer_id may have multiple plots those hold sy_nos

Comment: Still not clear. Sorry. There are farmers A, B, C and there are plots 1, 2, 3. Table weighment_tran may have entries for A1, A2, B2, B3 and three entries for C3. The table has no unique key. Table agreement_tran may have entries for A2, A3, B1, two entries for B3 and entries for C1 and C3. This table, too, has no unique key. Then every plot has a unique sy_no, say 100 for plot 1, 200 for plot 2 and 300 for plot 3. Right so far? Do you notice that you let us guess? It is neither clear how your tables are related, nor what you want to show exactly. Plots? Farmers? Agreements?

Comment: A, B, C are farmers. they have 1, 2, 3 farmer_id respectively. farmer A have plots P1, P2, P3, farmer B have p3, p4 plots. if farmer A register P1, P2 plots for supply we collect register_id, Payment_id. for instance farmer A register his plot P1 with a data like register_id 2 of farmer B and payment_id 3 of farmer C. then every supply of plot P1 weighed and stored in weighment_tran. finally payment is made to farmer C for every supply weighed as he is authorized to paid.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying hard to follow, but fail. It seems neither a plot nor a farmer must belong to only one village. So there are weighments (whatever this is) that keep records of farmers working on a part of a plot belonging to a particular village and that part of the plot or that work is registered to still another farmer. At least so it seems. (Still I have no idea how the tables are related and what are there keys.) And then a farmer can register a plot, but it would be registered to a second farmer and then even a third farmer pays for it? And again: what do you want to select?

Comment: Finally my effort rewarded me